# NodeJS express framework reads the same event multiple times

Tags: node.js, http, express, wso2

I'm working with a service (WSO2CEP) that sends events to a node js program that I developed, let's call it receiver.js, and then it stores these events in a mongo db. The comunication between WSO2CEP and receiver.js is done through a HTTP connection. The problem I'm facing on is that when the WSO2 sends an event, the receiver.js caputres it and stores it in the db, and after a few seconds/minutes, it detects that a new events has arrived, which is not true, and stores it again in the db. This second event is identical to the first one.

When I saw that I thought that the problem was that the WSO2 was sending the same event multiple times, but I've debug it an I'm 100% sure that only one events is being sent, so the problem seems to be the HTTP connection.

The HTTP connection is being handled by the receiver.js acting as a server and WSO2 as a client, which sends the events through HTTP post request. The http server implementation in receiver.js is done with the "express" framework. As it can be seen in below code chunk.

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const   port = Whatever;


module.exports = class WSO2Server extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const   app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies

    app.route('/Whatever').post( (req, res) => {
      let event = req.body;
      this.emit('event', event);
    });

    this.server = app.listen(port);
  }

  destroy () {
    this.server.close();
  }
}
```

I suspect that the events are being stored in a queu (or similar) and are being retransmitted every so often. Any idea about that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I can't see you using the response object at all. After you've called `this.emit('event', event);` you should call something like `res.status(201).end();` which will dispatch a HTTP Status 201 back to the calling client.

Because you're not setting any information on the response object, your application is hanging and not making a response to the HTTP call. Thus something like nginx or apache is re-issuing the request to your application after a specific timeout.

If you explicitly create the response with something `res.status(201).end();` then your request will end correctly and a duplicate call will not be made.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem :)

Comment: @AngelRubi brilliant! Glad you got it fixed, I'll update my answer to be more assertive, I wasn't 100% sure it was going to be the problem.